# Filtering attribute table based on names in another table using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, select-by-attribute

I have a shapefile showing a list of district names. I have (currently in Excel) a long list of district names in a table. I would like to filter those districts that are in the other list. I think this is something to do with the attribute table and an expression, but I don;t know the expression for "this name is another another list".

Comment: Which list are you referring when you said `the other list`? Is it the one in the excel file or the shapefile?

Comment: It would the list that is in the excel file. So I would like to highlight those districts in the shapefile that match entries in a separate list of districts in an excel file

Answer (score 1):

Try using the 'Join attribute by field value' processing tool

Assuming that both tables have a field in common. I.e. link the two together on district code and then filter your data once joined.